# How can I have a repeating line of one image to the left, repeating line of another image to the right of a central html element?

Tags: html, css

I have a button constructed from an a tag within a div which is centered on the page horizontally, I'd like to place a line of images representing \ on the left and / on the right of the button, so it would be line this: \\\\\ button //////// and these would extend to the left and right edges of the page (should be automatically responsive).

I tried using ::before and ::after but could only get one image to appear (badly formed) and only on the left, also looked at using gradients but couldn't get it to form the graphics that I wanted and not with the left/right difference.

My code:

```
<div class="button-container text-center contact-button">
      <a class="button" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
</div>




.contact-button::before {
    content: '';
    background: url("img/chevron-left.png") repeat-x;
    height: 40px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact-button::after {
    content: '';
    background: url('img/chevron-right.png') repeat-x;
    height: 40px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have one image (svg or png, take your pick) for the left \ and another for / with a specific colour and angles.  Any pointers on this please?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: can you provide sny image of your idea , try to build the idea on figma or photoshop and share your idea just so that your context will be visual

Comment: I added a screen shot showing my idea which is exactly the way it came out with the accepted solution + a few tweaks, so all is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background images aren't repeating because they're both inside divs only 20px wide. You need the divs to stretch to all the way to the left and right of the page. Since you don't know what size the page will be, you could use a grid layout on the parent, like this:

```
<div class="button-container text-center contact-button">
    <a class="button" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
</div>

.button-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content 1fr;
}

.button-container:before {
    content: "";
    background: url("chevron-left.png") repeat-x;
    background-position: right; 
}

.button-container:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('chevron-right.png') repeat-x;
    background-position: left; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That led me down the right track for sure, my final solution contained a few extra tweaks but is basically the same.

Answer (score -1):

My final solution:

```
.button-container.contact-button {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content 1fr;
}

.contact-button .button {
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.contact-button::before {
    content: "";
    background: url("img/chevron-left.svg") repeat-x;
    background-size: 20px 90px;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    background-position-x: right;
}

.contact-button::after {
    content: "";
    background: url("img/chevron-right.svg") repeat-x;
    background-size: 20px 90px;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    background-position-x: left;
}
```

Which gives this:
[image: Button with ::before and ::after images]